# Why won't this Angular ng-bind tie to an ng-controller?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm learning Angular.js. I want to make a `form` where the user can see the output has they fill it out.

Here's `test.html`:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="charter">
  <div id="layout-wrapper" ng-controller="graphicLanguageCTRL">
        <form id="graphic-language" ng-controller="graphicLanguageCTRL" novalidate>
            <h3>Language</h3>
            <input type="text" name="headline" placeholder="Headline" ng-model="graphic.hed"> <br>
        </form>
  </div>
  <h1 class="graphic-title" ng-bind="graphic.hed"></h1>
</body>
```

Here's `test.js`:

```
var app=    angular.module("charter",[]);
app.controller("graphicLanguageCTRL",function($scope){
    $scope.master=  {
        hed: ''
    };
});
```

I want the stuff typed into the `input` tag to be visible in the `h1` tag. But when I type into the `input` tag, nothing appears in the `h1` tag.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some errors in your code:

- You are using ng-bind outside of controller
- You are initializing `graphicLanguageCTRL` twice
- In your script you are setting the wrong variable name

Below is the fixed code:

html

```
<body ng-app="charter">
  <div id="layout-wrapper" ng-controller="graphicLanguageCTRL">
    <form id="graphic-language" novalidate>
      <h3>Language</h3>
      <input type="text" name="headline" placeholder="Headline" ng-model="graphic.hed"> <br>
    </form>
    <h1 class="graphic-title" ng-bind="graphic.hed"></h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module("charter",[]);

app.controller("graphicLanguageCTRL", function($scope){
  $scope.graphic = {
    hed : ''
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module("charter",[]);
app.controller("graphicLanguageCTRL",function($scope){
    $scope.graphic = {
        hed: ''
    };
});
```

or

```
var app = angular.module("charter",[]);
app.controller("graphicLanguageCTRL",function($scope){
    $scope.graphic = {};
    $scope.graphic.head = ''
});
```

Comment: Reduce the code to the minimum needed and add some comments to make a question more useful.

Answer (score 0):

2 things need to be taken care of:

- Do not nest and use the same `ng-controller`
- Move the `h1` inside
  the `ng-controller` block

**Fixed version:**

```js
var app = angular.module('charter', []);
app.controller("graphicLanguageCTRL", function($scope) {
  $scope.graphic = {
    hed: ''
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-app='charter'>
  <div id="layout-wrapper" ng-controller="graphicLanguageCTRL">
    <form id="graphic-language" novalidate>
      <h3>Language</h3>
      <input type="text" name="headline" placeholder="Headline" ng-model="graphic.hed">
      <br>
    </form>
    <h1 class="graphic-title" ng-bind="graphic.hed"></h1>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```